# Change Button/Textfield at runtime with a new class

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm displaying a winforms with a button and a textfield (names: button1, textBox1).
I want to change the text of the button and textbox on the fly over a other .cs file (cobra.cs as example). On my Program.cs i use this to draw the winform:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace bombtimer
{
    class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Der Haupteinstiegspunkt für die Anwendung.
        /// </summary>
        //[STAThread]
        public static Form1 formInstance;
        static void Main()
        {

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(formInstance = new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

and my cobra.cs:

```
using System;
using CSGSI;

public static class Globals
{
    public static Int32 countdown = 0;
}

namespace GSI_Test
{


    class Program_Cobra
    {
        static void Main_cobra(string[] args)
        {

            ... stuff...
            if (GSIListener.Start(10))
            {
                //Change textbox text to: "OK"
            }
            else
            {
                //Change textbox text to: "NOT OK"
            }
        }
        public static void OnNewGameState(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ...stuff...
        }
    }
}
```

How can i change the button and textbox? :S

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure is this best solution or not but you can use a timer in your winform and set the button text inside of timer from a static string variable in the cobra class.
(sorry for my English)